# Mediawiki skin creation - Javascripts don't get loaded

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki, skin

Trying to do a new skin for Mediawiki. CSS files are loading, but not the JavaScript files.  In the script.js file, I only have a simple alert statement, but nothing happens when the page gets loaded.

NewSkin.php file:

```
<?php    
if( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
   die( 'This is a skin to the MediaWiki package and cannot be run standalone.' );
}    
$wgExtensionCredits['skin'][] = array(
    'path'       => __FILE__,
    'name'       => 'newskin',
    'url'        => 'http://exmaple.com/',
    'version'    => '1.2-alpha',
    'author'     => array(
        'Author Name',      
        ),
    'descriptionmsg' => 'newskin-desc'
);    
$wgValidSkinNames['newskin'] = 'NewSkin';    
$wgAutoloadClasses['SkinNewSkin'] = __DIR__ . '/NewSkin.skin.php';    
$wgMessagesDirs['SkinNewSkin'] = __DIR__ . '/i18n';    
$wgResourceModules['skins.newskin'] = array(
    'styles'         => array(
        'newskin/resources/bootstrap.css',
        'newskin/resources/styles.css',     
    ),
    'scripts'  => array(
        'newskin/resources/jquery.js',
        'newskin/resources/script.js',            
    ),
    'remoteBasePath' => &$GLOBALS['wgStylePath'],
    'localBasePath'  => &$GLOBALS['wgStyleDirectory']
);
?>
```

NewSkin.skin.php file:

```
<?php
class SkinNewSkin extends SkinTemplate {

    var $skinname = 'newskin', $stylename = 'newskin',
        $template = 'NewSkinTemplate', $useHeadElement = true;

    public function initPage( OutputPage $out ) {
        parent::initPage( $out );

        /* Assures mobile devices that the site doesn't assume traditional
         * desktop dimensions, so they won't downscale and will instead respect
         * things like CSS's @media rules */
        $out->addHeadItem( 'viewport',
            '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />'
        );
        $out->addModuleScripts('skins.newskin');
    }

    /**
     * @param $out OutputPage object
     */
    function setupSkinUserCss( OutputPage $out ) {
        parent::setupSkinUserCss( $out );
        $out->addModuleStyles( 'skins.newskin' );       
    }   
}

class NewSkinTemplate extends BaseTemplate {    
    public function execute() { 
        $this->html( 'headelement' ); 
        $this->html( 'bodytext' );  
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is `jquery.js` just jQuery? If so, remove it (mediawiki has jQuery built-in).

Comment: yes, however, in addition to that i need bootstrap.js and another custom.js imported too. Not sure what' I'm missing here.

Comment: Well I don't see anything wrong with the PHP code. Are there any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: I tried to copy code from the vector skin and translate them. That seems working for me.

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript code, too, please?

Comment: In the script.js file, didn't' have much javascript except a simple  'alert('test')' statement.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any place where we can check the js error?

if you are building a Mediawiki skin using bootstrap then you can start from one of the existing ones. I developed the skin MediaWikiBoostrap (https://github.com/nasirkhan/mediawiki-bootstrap) i hope this will help you to solve the issue.